# Why is IIS using native versions of .NET System DLLs?

Tags: .net, iis, dll, clr, native

In Process Explorer, I see that IIS is loading the native versions of some of the System DLLs instead of the regular managed ones.
For example, I see Microsoft.JScript.ni.dll, System.Data.ni.dll, mscorlib.ni.dll and a couple more.

At no point did anyone run ngen on this server.

It's Windows 2008 R2.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngen is run when the framework is installed. These are commonly used assemblies so .net assumes you'll be using them & optimises it's for you.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, that makes sense. I'm just wondering how it is then that on most other servers, I see that the "regular" non-native versions of these DLLs are loaded. Any idea?

Comment: I can't really say. Perhaps it's something in 2008 R2? Someone from Microsoft is probably better suited to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

That's the result of work by [Ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) - precompiling assemblies into native code (instead of JIT) to increase their performance.

Ngen state for Native Image Generator, so .ni.dll means the same - native image.

Comment: Actually, @abatishchev, we never ran ngen on the server.

Comment: @Leor: As Simon stated correctly, it's being ran automatically.